# Why do some methods accept only blocks as arguments in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arguments

Methods like `maps` and `collect` only accept blocks. If blocks are not objects and can't be saved to variables, then why do these methods need them as arguments?

```
multiples_of_2 = Proc.new do |x|
  x % 2 == 0
end    
sq = Proc.new { |x| x ** 2 }

(1..50).to_a.select(&multiples_of_2) # => works properly
(1..50).to_a.select(multiples_of_2) # => `wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)`
[4, 5, 6].map!(sq) # => `wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)`
[10, 12, 14].collect!(sq) # => `wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)`
```

Comment: The ruby syntax obliged you to aknowledge the receiver that you are passing an object, responding to a `to_proc` instance method, rather than a block, by prepending the argument with an ampersand. As a payback you have an option (used a way more frequent than passing `#to_proc`ables) to pass the block explicitly as `each { |a| puts a }`.

Comment: Apologies, but I didn't get quite you. Do me a favour and use layman's terms, please.

Comment: Whether you want to pass an instance of an object, responding to `to_proc`, to a method, expecting block, just prepend it with an ampersand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Matz analyzed the usage of higher-order procedures in languages such as Common Lisp, Smalltalk, and ML before designing Ruby, and he noticed that the vast majority of higher-order procedures take exactly *one* first-class procedure as argument and they don't store it or pass it on but just call it. And of the ones that take more than one first-class procedure as arguments, a significant number are control structures such as conditionals and loops which he didn't want to have as methods anyway.

So, the result of his analysis was: having a construct that allows you to pass exactly *one* block of code to a method that isn't stored or processed further, just executed, was enough to cover 80% of all cases. From my personal experience, I can certainly attest to that. The only time I ever needed more than one block, was when I wanted to show what an implementation of `if`/`then`/`else` as a method would look like.

As a result, he devised a syntactically and semantically lightweight way to pass a single block of code to a method. This restriction allows some conveniences. For example, if you know that there cannot be more than one block, then you don't need to name it, because you always know which block you are talking about (there is only one). This allows something like the syntactically lightweight `yield` keyword to work: you can just say `yield` without having to specify *where* to yield *to*, because there is only one block.

However, for those cases where you need to be able to pass more than one chunk of executable code, or store and process it further, we have `Proc`s, and we have an easy way to convert between `Proc`s and blocks: in a parameter list, the `&` sigil means "package the block into a `Proc` and bind it to this name" and in an argument list, the `&` unary prefix operator means "unpackage the `Proc` into a block" (and if it isn't a `Proc`, convert it to one first by calling `to_proc`).

Now that we have stabby lambda literals, the difference between having blocks in the language and not having them is not so great as it once was:

```
enum.map(-> e { e ** 2 })
# vs.
enum.map {|e| e ** 2 }
```

But before Ruby 1.9, the difference was:

```
enum.map(Proc.new {|e| e ** 2 })
# vs.
enum.map {|e| e ** 2 }
```

Umm, well, actually we are cheating here! We are passing a block to `Proc.new` in the first place! But we just said, what if we *didn't* have blocks? Then that obviously wouldn't work either. You would instead have to do something like this:

```
def (sq = Proc.new).call(e) e ** 2 end; enum.map(sq)
# vs.
enum.map {|e| e ** 2 }
```

That's some significant syntactic overhead compared to having blocks in the language!

So, that's why we have blocks, and why methods like `map`, which only care about one chunk of code and don't need to actually store it anywhere, take a block.